# wrap material ui Table inside div

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

```
render () {
    const { classes, intl, userFormData } = this.props
    const { open, usersList, isSomeFilterSelected, selected } = this.state
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <Paper className={classes.table}>
            {selected.length === 0 ? <div
              className={classNames(classes.buttons, isSomeFilterSelected ? classes.filterSelected : classes.filterAreNotSelected)}>
              {isSomeFilterSelected ? <div onClick={this.onClearFilters}>
                <Button className={classes.button}>
                  {intl.formatMessage(messages.clear)}
                  <DeleteIcon className={classes.rightIcon}/>
                </Button>
              </div> : null}
              <UserTableFilterForm
                onSubmit={this.onHandleSubmit}
                open={open}
                handleOpenStateClose={this.onHandleOpenFilters}
                handleOpenStateOpen={this.onHandleCloseFilters}
                switcher={userFormData['switchField'] ? userFormData['switchField'] : false}
              />
            </div> : null}
            {selected.length !== 0 ? <TableToolbar
              numSelected={selected.length}
              handleOnDeleteAction={this.onHandleDeleteSelectedUsers}
            /> : null}
            <Table>
              <TableHead
                onSelectAllClick={this.onSelectAllUsersFromTableForDelete}
                numSelected={selected.length}
                rowCount={usersList.length}
              />
              <TableBody
                {...this.state}
                onHandleSelected={this.onHandleSelected}
                isSelected={this.isSelected}
              />
            </Table>
            <TableFooter
              {...this.state}
              onHandlePageParameter={this.onHandlePageParameter}
              onHandleChangeRowsPerPage={this.onHandleChangeRowsPerPage}
            />
          </Paper>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Above you can see my code , below you can see the error which occur when I load this page , I want to wrap table inside div , but can't find how to solve it , pls help , and I tried to find in which parent can occur Table and td , but haven't found also

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of
>   .
>       in td (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in TableCell (created by WithStyles(TableCell))
>       in WithStyles(TableCell) (created by TablePagination)
>       in TablePagination (created by WithStyles(TablePagination))
>       in WithStyles(TablePagination) (created by TableFooter)
>       in TableFooter (created by WithStyles(TableFooter))
>       in WithStyles(TableFooter) (created by InjectIntl(WithStyles(TableFooter)))
>       in InjectIntl(WithStyles(TableFooter)) (created by UsersPage)
>       in div (created by Paper)
>       in Paper (created by WithStyles(Paper))
>       in WithStyles(Paper) (created by mapProps(WithStyles(Paper)))
>       in mapProps(WithStyles(Paper)) (created by WithStyles(mapProps(WithStyles(Paper))))
>       in WithStyles(mapProps(WithStyles(Paper))) (created by UsersPage)
>       in div (created by UsersPage)
>       in div (created by UsersPage)
>       in UsersPage (created by Connect(UsersPage))
>       in Connect(UsersPage) (created by WithStyles(Connect(UsersPage)))
>       in WithStyles(Connect(UsersPage)) (created by InjectIntl(WithStyles(Connect(UsersPage))))
>       in InjectIntl(WithStyles(Connect(UsersPage))) (created by UniversalComponent)
>       in UniversalComponent (created by Route)
>       in div (created by MainLayout)
>       in div (created by MainLayout)
>       in div (created by MainLayout)
>       in div (created by MainLayout)
>       in MainLayout (created by WithStyles(MainLayout))
>       in WithStyles(MainLayout) (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by PageRoute)
>       in PageRoute (created by _default)
>       in Switch (created by _default)
>       in _default (created by Application)
>       in IntlProvider (created by Connect(IntlProvider))
>       in Connect(IntlProvider) (created by Application)
>       in Application (created by Connect(Application))
>       in Connect(Application)
>       in MuiThemeProviderOld
>       in JssProvider
>       in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
>       in ConnectedRouter (created by Connect(ConnectedRouter))
>       in Connect(ConnectedRouter)
>       in Provider

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only issue, but your `TableFooter` element should be inside the `Table`.

```
    <TableFooter
      {...this.state}
      onHandlePageParameter={this.onHandlePageParameter}
      onHandleChangeRowsPerPage={this.onHandleChangeRowsPerPage}
    />
    </Table>
```

instead of:

```
    </Table>
    <TableFooter
      {...this.state}
      onHandlePageParameter={this.onHandlePageParameter}
      onHandleChangeRowsPerPage={this.onHandleChangeRowsPerPage}
    />
```